# Asmx WebService static constructor getting called more then once

Tags: c#, web-services, static, constructor, asmx

Static constructor should be called once when the first method is called.
My constructor called every time method is called. 
any idea Why is this happening?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SimpleWS
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        static WebService1()
        {
            //initialize
            //write to log file
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string test()
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is because static constructor is called when type is initialized. In case of web server type initialization may occur each time the server creates new 'instance' of your assembly to process client request.

Comment: If you have configured a web-garden, each worker process will call the static ctor once

Comment: I noticed that the behavior is different on different servers.
Does that makes sense?

Comment: Print the process id when you "log" within the static ctor.  If you see that the process ids are different, then that means you've configured your application pool to leverage more than one worker process. Also, unless you have configured your app pool to always be up, the app pool will automatically shutdown if it is idle, which means the next time a request comes in, it will go through the type initialization again (as Artemix mentioned).

Comment: Why process details are empty?      
   ProcessID=0    
   Age=00:00:00    
   PeakMemoryUsed=0    
   RequestCount=0    
   ShutdownReason=None    
   StartTime=01/01/0001 00:00:00    
   Status=0